# Can I use join command to join two files that have similarities on different column?

Tags: linux, unix, join

I have two files. one with three column (file 1):

```
AX-76297970 24 1000227
AX-76297974 24 1000999
AX-76297977 24 1001279
AX-76297978 24 1001552
AX-76297979 24 1001892
AX-76297985 24 1002443
AX-76297989 24 1002815
AX-76297993 24 1003894
AX-76297994 24 1004444
```

and another with several columns (file 2):

```
24      991     3       2       51.39   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       -5      1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
24      1000227    4       1       35496.64        0       0       0.077   0       0       0.077   0       0       0       0       0.308   0       0       0       0       -5      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
24      1068    3       4       257.06  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       -5      1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
24      1002443    4       2       66.67   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       -5      1       1       1       1       1       0.95    1       1       1
24      1094    3       4       98.21   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

what I want to do is to join these two files on column 3 of file 1 and column 2 of file 2.to get an output of all the columns of file 2 like this:

```
24      1000227    4       1       35496.64        0       0       0.077   0       0       0.077   0       0       0       0       0.308   0       0       0       0       -5      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0

24      1002443    4       2       66.67   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       -5      1       1       1       1       1       0.95    1       1       1
```

If you have the solution can you please explain it in detail so I can use it for different columns.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you know `R` the `merge` and `match` command can solve the problem.

Comment: So you want to find those lines in file2 whose 2nd column is found in a 3rd column of file1? If so, `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$3]; next} $2 in a' f1 f2` makes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
 join -1 3 -2 2 file1 file2

 -1 3 tells join to use column three (3) of the first file (-1)
 -2 2 tells join to use column two (2) of the second file (-2)
```

should do it. Maybe you will need to specify the separator:

```
 join -t '\t' -1 3 -2 2 file1 file2
```

Have a look at the man page for the `join` command.

Comment: What is the different between those that have `-` and those that do not have `-`? Is that related to the first and second file respectively.

Comment: So, it can be used with 3 files

Comment: @user1436187: you don't like reading man pages, do you? 'join' will join lines of two files on a common field, not three, four or any other number!

Comment: Thanks. I get the sort error! although that both files are sorted! and I also sorted them on 2nd and 3rd column but still get the same error!

Comment: Have you used "sort -b" to sort your files?